# LWC: lightning-record-form not respecting required attribute on Page Layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

I have the following LWC Component:
"
    "
I have created a Page Layout for the recordType and marked a few fields as required on the Page Layout. While the fields are being pulled into the layout, they are not being shown as required, and I am able to save the Record without populating information in the fields. Is there anything extra that I need to do so that the required symbol comes up against the field?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: have you specified RecordId on the component as attribute?

Comment: This is the code, I am using this to create a record, hence no need to specify Record Id: <lightning-record-form
        object-api-name={objectAPIName}
        record-type-id={recordTypeId}
        layout-type="Full"
        onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
    </lightning-record-form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation. It only marks required on Object Level.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation

lightning-record-form renders a field as required only if the field is marked as required on the object. If a field is marked as required only on a page layout, the form doesn't render the field with the styling or validation for a required field.

Comment: Thank You. I totally missed that in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

As ytiq already answered lightning-record-form renders a field as required only if the field is marked as required on the object but you can use lightning record edit form with lightning input field with required attribute to make it required.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lwc_components.htm